# What OTP behaviors should I use for such module?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have simple erlang module and I want to rewrite it based on OTP principles. But I can not determine what opt template I should use.

Module's code:

```
-module(main).

-export([start/0, loop/0]).

start() -> 
    Mypid = spawn(main, loop, []),
    register( main, Mypid).

loop() ->
    receive
        [Pid, getinfo] -> Pid! [self(), welcome],
            io:fwrite( "Got ~p.~n", [Pid] ),
            // spawn new process here
            loop();
        quit -> ok;
        X ->
            io:fwrite( "Got ~p.~n", [ X ] ),
            // spawn new process here
            loop()
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gen_server would be fine.

Couple things:

- it is a bad practice to send message to yourself
- messages are usually tuples not lists because they are not dynamic
- despite your comment, you do not spawn the new process.
  Call to loop/0 enters the same loop.

Gen_server init would hold your start/0 body. API calls sequence and proxy your calls via gen_server to handle_calls. To spawn new process on function call, add spawn function to the body of desired handle_call. Do not use handle_info to handle incoming messages -- instead of sending them call the gen_server API and 'translate' your call into gen_server:call or cast. e.g.

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init(_) ->
    {ok, #state{}}

welcome(Arg) ->
   gen_server:cast(?MODULE, {welcome, Arg}).

handle_cast({welcome, Arg},_,State) ->
  io:format("gen_server PID: ~p~n", [self()]),
  spawn(?MODULE, some_fun, [Arg]),
  {noreply, State}

some_fun(Arg) ->
  io:format("Incoming arguments ~p to me: ~p~n",[Arg, self()]).
```

I have never compiled above, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but where should a receive part be? or can I receive message by `?MODULE` process in spawned `some_fun` process?

Comment: the receive body is hidden from you in the `gen_server` module. message reception occurs through the callback functions

Comment: yup.. the ! syntax is fancy but it is also hard to trace. In real systems, parallelization is hidden in well known behaviours (like gen_srv) and wrapped around function calls.

Comment: Yes you can receive messages in new process.. but you need to know its PID to send messages to it in the first place. To solve that, use handle_call and return PID. BTW. handle_info is basically receive block for gen_* behaviours, but as I said before, exported API is better.